# Sources to read about human body described in hinduism

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to read about human body described in hindu scriptures.
If there is any please provide links or references or books?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an Ayurvedic perspective, there is the the Sharirasthana of the Sushruta-samhita which deals with anatomy and the human body (sharira), and various other subjects:

http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-3-sharirasthana

A small chapter from the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad also deals with the Sharira (body):

http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc120048.html

And from the advaita-vedanta perspective, we have the Taittiriya Upanishad where five chapters are dedicated to the five layers (kośa, ‘sheats’) of a human being:

Book II: Brahmavalli, Part A: Brahmavidyā expounded:
[Chapter XI - Annamaya-kośa](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79813.html) 
[Chapter XII - Prāṇamaya-kośa](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79815.html) 
[Chapter XIII - Manomaya-kośa](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79817.html) 
[Chapter XIV - Vijñānamaya-kośa](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79819.html) 
[Chapter XV - Ānandamaya-kośa](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79821.html)

And finally, the ‘Vedic index of names and subjects’ also has a detailed definition on the human body (sharira) including many references to Vedic literature:

https://archive.org/stream/vedicindexofname02macduoft#page/358/mode/2up